# FileSystemWatcher - The directory name does not exist

Tags: c#, .net, filesystemwatcher

I have a FileSystemWatcher hosted as a windows service, works fine when pointed to a local folder. but if I point to a network folder in the same server

```
fileWatcher.Path = "\\uskansclapd01\\Input";
```

Receiving error "The directory name does not exist" error. I thought this may be due to permission issue and I have given access to everyone for the network folder but did not help.

Comment: You need to use backslashes and escapes correctly: use either `fileWatcher.Path = "\\\\uskansclapd01\\Input";` or `fileWatcher.Path = @"\\uskansclapd01\Input"` - or even `@"\\?\UNC\uskansclapd01\Input\"` if you want to fight `MAX_PATH`.

Comment: @Dai escaping the backslashes worked like a charm. Thank you!. Can you add your comment as answer.

Answer (score -1):

Have you manually set the user in the window service or is it set to local account?
Try to set a user and give explecit read permissions to that user.

Since using a local folder works, [mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/gg651155(v=ws.11))  the unit should make the trick.